# External HDMI monitor not detected in Ubuntu/Xubuntu 18.04 in Dell Inspiron 5593 nvidia

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm unable to use any external monitor in my new Dell Inspiron 5593 equiped with nvidia geforce.

I tried with nvidia drivers and xorg, but there is been no change.

Checking out xrand it says:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

If I try to add some new mode, for instance:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1200x1000_60.00
```

I get:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI1"
```

The monitor of my laptop works, but all the parameters: resolution, refresh etc. ...  cannot be changed.

I'm not even close to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

It turned out that the CPU Intel i5 of 10th generation is too new for the kernel I had. The solution was to update the linux kernel.